# ¿A que se debe este comportamiento de ngfor y ngif?

Tags: ionic3

He creado un `accordion list`. Este `accordion list` lo creo a partir de un json obtenido desde una consulta post.

Cuando tengo la respuesta json, creo el `accordion list`. Creo el primer nivel del accordion pero al desplegarlo, dependiendo de un valor, muestro una imagen o no.

El mostrar o no la imagen lo hago evaluando una propiedad de una variable.
Además de mostrar la imagen, llamo a un método que simplemente llama a un alert.

Mi problema es que la imagen si que me la muestra solo una vez pero el alert me lo muestra varias veces...

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<label *ngFor="let variable of placa.variablesplaca;" no-padding>

    <div *ngIf="variable.magnitud.magnitud === 'final de carrera' && variable.senyal.orden === 1 && variable.valor === 1; else second">  
        <img src="../../assets/imgs/compuertaabierta.png" style="width: 12vh; height: 20vh"><br>
          {{ alertar('Abierta') }}
    </div>

    <div #second *ngIf="variable.magnitud.magnitud === 'final de carrera' && variable.senyal.orden == 2 && variable.valor == 1; else third">
        <img src="../../assets/imgs/compuertacerrada.png" style="width: 12vh; height: 20vh"><br>
          {{ alertar('Cerrada') }}
    </div>

    <div #third *ngIf="variable.magnitud.magnitud === 'final de carrera' && variable.valor == 0">
        <img src="../../assets/imgs/compuertasemi.png" style="width: 12vh; height: 20vh"><br>
          {{ alertar('Semi') }}
    </div>
</label>
```

En la respuesta del json tengo varias "variables" pero solo 2 cuya magnitud es "final de carrera" con lo cual, sólo debería entrar 2 veces a los `if` pero lo que veo es lo siguiente, me muestra 2 veces la imagen, eso está perfecto, pero me muestra el alertar muchas veces.

No se si lo he explicado bien, puedo explicar más mi caso si es oportuno o no se entiende bien.

Comment: Sólo no uses alertas. Angular va a redibujar tu acordeón cada vez que piense que *puede* haber un cambio. Como el flujo es top-to-bottom el componente padre a veces redibuja al hijo sin cambios explícitos de por medio, o bien comprueba las condiciones más de una vez cuando lo redibuja. Si en vez de la alerta usaras un `console.log` efectivamente verías que ese bucle se recorre más de  una vez, pero no se debe a ninguna falla en particular

Answer (score 1):

El ciclo de vida de los componentes de Angular hace que un componente se pueda redibujar varias veces, especialmente si estás probando en "modo desarrollo", donde cada comprobación se hace dos veces para comprobar que no hay efectos indeseados que puedan provocar un loop infinito de cambios.

Eso hará que ese `*ngFor` se ejecute al menos dos veces, puede que 4, al cargar el componente, mostrando el número de alertas por duplicado o cuadruplicado

Comment: si, me lo ejecuta 4 veces...

Comment: Buen punto lo del modo desarrollo. Cabe mencionar que esto también puede manejarse dándole un valor explícito a [ChangeDetectionStrategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) en la declaración del componente hijo (me parece que es en el hijo). Pero igual, hay bucles que se recorren más de una vez. Y si están anidados, Se pueden recorrer NxM veces.

Comment: @amenadiel Lo del ChangeDetectionStrategy lo dejo para otra pregunta más enfocada a ese tema, pero desde luego es bueno conocer cómo funciona y cómo afecta al ciclo de vida de los componentes

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, en realidad es mejor dejar eso para el día en que alguien diga: "porqué en mi consola se loguea como si el componente se dibujara 10 veces si no lo he cambiado...?"

Comment: Yo descubrí ese tema por justo lo contrario, mi componente no se actualizaba cuando yo quería porque modificaba el objeto input pero seguía siendo el mismo objeto 